# 400 Bad Request while Uploading large file to Google Drive with Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am creating one Google App Engine App in which I want to upload files to my Google Drive Folder.

For that I am using Google API Python Client Library.
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/

I am using MediaIoBaseUpload function from library because I am getting file content from one Form. And I am using resumable upload.

When I am uploading a file of smaller size around 15 MB it works fine, but files which are larger than 15 MB I am getting error 400 Bad Request in last chunk.

All previous chunks works fine, but last chunk returns error.

I am trying to uploading one zip file(around 46 MB).

Here is my code:

```
fh = io.BytesIO(self.fileContent)
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(fh, "application/zip", 1024 * 1024, resumable=True)
http = httplib2.Http()
if credentials.invalid is True:
    credentials.refresh(http)
else:
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

body = {
    'title': self.fileName,
    'description': "",
    "parents": [{
                    "kind": "drive#fileLink",
                    "id": self.folderId
                }],
    'mimeType': fileMimeType
  }

response = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media).execute()
```

Comment: Parent's kind is drive#parentReference, not drive#fileLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set a `kind` attribute for the parent. Use the following list instead:

```
"parents": [{ "id": self.folderId }]
```